# Why can't I see environment variables in Docker Desktop?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-desktop

I have a problem. Saw that while using Docker Desktop field **Environment variables** should be available, but they are absent on my Mac.

I asked for lecturer but he don't know the answer too. Look at the screenshot:[image: screenshot]

Please answer what is the reason of this problem and how can I fill this field from the Desktop. Have a good day!

I searched that on internet, read documentation, tried to delete and reinstall the images

Comment: What version of Docker Desktop are you using?